# PyInstaller executable Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyside2

I've created an executable with pyinstaller and I can execute it on the machine I built it, but when I transfer it to another machine and run it there, I get the following:

```
C:\>myApp.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 47
, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py", line 49
, in <module>
  File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pack
ages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 21, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pack
ages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[8272] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_qt5plugins
```

But I'm using PySide2, not PyQt5.

**EDIT: Resolved**

Not the best resolution, but I resolved this reinstalling Python, PySide2, and pyinstaller.  I also downgraded to Python 3.6.8 in the process, which may also have contributed to the success.

Comment: If you do not want to complicate your life with pyinstaller then or: 1) use venv that has only pyside2 OR 2) use [fbs](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs) that adjusts the paths to avoid having these problems.

Comment: I tried using a venv as well, but got a different error with that.

Comment: Then you will have to solve that *different error*, for me the simplest solution is to use fbs

Comment: what is fbs?  I couldn't tell from the github link

Comment: is a project that allows to generate specialized executables for Qt binding such as PySide2. Try it, you do not lose anything.